# MediaPlayer getProgess - incorrect values

Tags: android, audio

I'm using `MediaPlayer` to play some recorded audio and `SeekBar` to show the progress of the play. My problem is: when I click on the `SeekBar` to jump to a time position the following example happens and i see on the Log when i want to see the progess:

> getprogress(ms): 10000
>   getprogress(ms): 9956
>   getprogress(ms): 10000

So I jump to the recorded audio's 10th second. The `MediaPlayer` jumps to the 10th second but after It jumps back a bit as you can see.

I tried everything i could. I tried playing other recorder's audio files but happened the same. Tried playing with the bit rate and sampling rate but happened the same.

I hope someone knows the solution to this. Thank You.

**Edit:**

Code:

SeekBar:

```
progressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

        }

        @Override
         public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
           // handler2.removeCallbacks(updateTimeTask);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            if (PlayerForegroundService.player != null) {
             //   handler2.removeCallbacks(updateTimeTask);
                PlayerForegroundService.player.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
               // handler2.post(updateTimeTask);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.ACTION.PLAYER_UPDATE_UI));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

getProgess():

```
public int getProgress(){
    if ( player != null) {
        Log.i(Constants.DEFAULTS.LOG_TAG, ""+player.getCurrentPosition());
        return player.getCurrentPosition();
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

The code when getProgress gets called:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
            actPosition.setText(intent.getStringExtra("formattedtimeplay"));
            progressBar.setProgress(PlayerForegroundService.player.getProgress());
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra("pausedplay", false))
                playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.playfilled);
        }
    };
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.ACTION.PLAYER_UPDATE_UI));
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: where are you log this progress? I think to get a exact value, you should check it in onSeekComplete() of an onSeekCompleteListener...

Comment: where is your `MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener`?

Comment: the app doesn't have `OnSeekCompleteListener`

Comment: so add that listener

Comment: why should i add? how would that solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems i solved the problem. Before, I used to set the maximum value of the `SeekBar` in seconds. But after I set the max in milliseconds and the values of the `seekTo` in milliseconds it works fine.